# How can I use a Stored Procedure to INSERT a coy of an existing row with a small change?

Tags: sql-server

Can someone give me advice? I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [TestId]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentTestId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]      NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Title]          NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [TopicId]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [Release]        INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Identifier]     VARCHAR (25)   NULL
);
```

How I can create a Stored Procedure that will take an existing row in the table and insert a copy of that row.

I would like to be able to supply a new [CreatedBy] as an argument to the Stored Procedure and also for the new row I would like the [ParentId] to be set to the value of the [TestId] that the row is copied from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use an `insert` statement like:

```
insert into test(TestId, ParentTestId, CreatedBy, Title, TopicId, Release, Identifier)
    select TestId, @TestId, @CreatedBy, Title, TopicId, Release, Identifier
    from test
    where TestId = @TestId;
```

The rest is just defining the stored procedure to go around this.

Comment: Thanks. It is a lot simpler now you explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc abc
@createdby nvarchar(128)
as
insert into test (ParentTestId, CreatedBy, Title, TopicId, Release, Identifier)
select TestID, @CreatedBy, Title, TopicId, Release, Identifier from test
go
```

Then you could add a where clause to the select statement to say which testids you want to select ie

```
select TestID, @CreatedBy, Title, TopicId, Release, Identifier from test
where testid  =  1
```